# Debian 9 /etc/hosts File changed automatically

Tags: debian, vps, hosts

I have newly installed a PostFix server for email to my Debian 9 VPS. And tested for email and success. But I checked the `/etc/hosts` file, it listed unknowns of domain names and some of them are `tor` domain name. And if I close the file, and reopen it, it will change the list. I even can't edit the `/etc/hosts` file. I tried to edit the file with `nano` and `vi` but it said operation not permitted even under `sudo` and `root` user.

Here's some of the content:

```
0.0.0.0     thyrsi.com
0.0.0.0     Rainbow66.f3322.net
0.0.0.0     an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.su
0.0.0.0     rapid7cpfqnwxodo.onion.in.net
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.in.net
0.0.0.0     w.21-3n.xyz
0.0.0.0     img.sobot.com
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.sh
0.0.0.0     lsdu.b-cdn.net
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.tor2web.io
0.0.0.0     tor2web.io
0.0.0.0     aptgetgxqs3secda.onion.in.net
0.0.0.0     rapid7cpfqnwxodo.onion.ly
0.0.0.0     pastebin.com
127.0.0.1       localhost
0.0.0.0     doh.dns.sb
0.0.0.0     aptgetgxqs3secda.onion.pet
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.mn
0.0.0.0     an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.d2web.org
0.0.0.0     rapid7cpfqnwxodo.onion.pet
0.0.0.0     aptgetgxqs3secda.onion.ly
0.0.0.0     rainbow20.eatuo.com
0.0.0.0     rapid7cpfqnwxodo.tor2web.fyi
0.0.0.0     dns.rubyfish.cn
0.0.0.0     an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.timesync.su
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.to
127.0.1.1       debian
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.glass
0.0.0.0     an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.d2web.org
0.0.0.0     relay.tor2socks.in
0.0.0.0     timesync.su
0.0.0.0     dns.twnic.tw
0.0.0.0     doh.centraleu.pi-dns.com
0.0.0.0     aptgetgxqs3secda.tor2web.fyi
0.0.0.0     lsd.systemten.org
107.173.160.159     laman.website
0.0.0.0     w.3ei.xyz
0.0.0.0     gitee.com
0.0.0.0     aliyun.one
0.0.0.0     upir.ir
0.0.0.0     trumpzwlvlyrvlss.onion
```

After I close and reopen:

```
0.0.0.0     thyrsi.com
0.0.0.0     img.sobot.com
127.0.0.1       localhost
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.mn
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.d2web.org
0.0.0.0     rapid7cpfqnwxodo.onion.pet
0.0.0.0     rapid7cpfqnwxodo.onion.ly
127.0.1.1       debian
0.0.0.0     timesync.su
0.0.0.0     upir.ir
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.sh
0.0.0.0     rapid7cpfqnwxodo.tor2web.fyi
0.0.0.0     gitee.com
0.0.0.0     aliyun.one
0.0.0.0     Rainbow66.f3322.net
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.in.net
0.0.0.0     pastebin.com
0.0.0.0     dns.twnic.tw
0.0.0.0     doh.centraleu.pi-dns.com
0.0.0.0     aptgetgxqs3secda.onion.in.net
0.0.0.0     aptgetgxqs3secda.onion.ly
0.0.0.0     rainbow20.eatuo.com
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.to
0.0.0.0     an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.d2web.org
0.0.0.0     w.21-3n.xyz
0.0.0.0     doh.dns.sb
0.0.0.0     dns.rubyfish.cn
0.0.0.0     lsd.systemten.org
0.0.0.0     trumpzwlvlyrvlss.onion
0.0.0.0     w.3ei.xyz
0.0.0.0     rapid7cpfqnwxodo.onion.in.net
0.0.0.0     an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh
0.0.0.0     an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.timesync.su
0.0.0.0     relay.tor2socks.in
0.0.0.0     aptgetgxqs3secda.tor2web.fyi
107.173.160.159     laman.website
0.0.0.0     an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.su
0.0.0.0     lsdu.b-cdn.net
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.tor2web.io
0.0.0.0     tor2web.io
0.0.0.0     aptgetgxqs3secda.onion.pet
0.0.0.0     intelbagjop7nzm5.onion.glass
```

I dont think this is normal. I have installed other server (vps) with same debian 9 and nothing of this issue appeared.

Anyone knows whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://s.tencent.com/research/report/948.html ([translated from Chinese by Google](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fs.tencent.com%2Fresearch%2Freport%2F948.html)), this is how **cryptomining malware** prevents its competition from working properly. The linked article describes a particular strain,

> DDG botnets mainly make profits by scanning SSH services and Redis services, invading Linux systems, and digging for Monero coins.
>
> Tencent Security found that DDG botnets are updated frequently, and a total of 9 versions have been updated in the most recent month, average weekly Update 2 versions (DDG / 5015-DDG / 5023)

...but obviously you can't make an exact diagnosis only based on the contents of the hosts file.

Comment: how do I prevent it? Now it start invading some of my servers. But no files are compromise yet, just the hosts file keep changed by itself.